# icacls - Invalid parameter error

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2008-r2, icacls

With Server 2008 R2, I'm using the following command and it works well:

```
icacls “D:\wamp\apache” /grant “run_apache”:(OI)(CI)RX /T
```

However, using

```
icacls “D:\wamp\apache\logs” /grant “run_apache”:(OI)(CI)RWXD /T
```

results in this error message:

```
Invalid parameter “run_apache:(OI)(CI)RWXD”
```

Could you tel me what’s wrong with it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Using your command, I get the same error. But if I change it to use `RXWD` instead of `RWXD` it works:

```
icacls "D:\wamp\apache\logs" /grant "run_apache":(OI)(CI)RXWD /T
```

The reason for this is that `RXWD` is the combination of the three permissions `RX` + `W` + `D`.

The permission masks can be seen by typing `icacls /?`:

```
ICACLS name [/grant[:r] Sid:perm[...]]
    /grant[:r] Sid:perm grants the specified user access rights. With :r,
        the permissions replace any previously granted explicit permissions.
        Without :r, the permissions are added to any previously granted
        explicit permissions.
    perm is a permission mask and can be specified in one of two forms:
        a sequence of simple rights:
                N - no access
                F - full access
                M - modify access
                RX - read and execute access
                R - read-only access
                W - write-only access
                D - delete access
```